# about mounting and root directory

Tags: mount, partition, directory, root

I am new to Linux and trying to understand partitioning and mounting so that I get to use arch Linux (i know it is a hard choice but I want it).

So the problem is I am a little confused about mounting what I understand is that when you mount a filesystem to a directory like /mnt the partition on which the filesystem resides will be accessible only through the /mnt directory and whenever I read more they say it does not matter on which folder you mount your devices and here comes the confusion if I mount all my devices to a folder like /mnt where would the rest of the root directory reside like the other files like /boot, /dev and /etc, etc...(pun intended).

Hope you do not render my question invalid please so I start understanding linux more and Thank you.

Comment: The system sees your files as being located at the mount point - this takes care of complications such as what filesystem you are using, whether it has special options etc. You just open, close, read, write to files as if they have a physical existence at the mount point.

Answer (score 1):

The root filesystem in Linux is always mounted in `/`. When you're working with any Live Linux distribution, it's again this Live Linux's root FS which is mounted in `/`.

Devices are always mounted into `/dev`.
Proc is always mounted into `/proc`.
Sys is always mounted into `/sys`.

The UEFI system partition is normally mounted into `/boot/efi` and the boot partition into `/boot`.

Linux applications are hardcoded against these paths.